# Openning JSON file, (NDJSON, new line delimited) -- big file

Tags: import, data, dataset, json-format, databases

I am trying since many hours to open a JSON file ("new line delimited") that has this as structure

```
{"Id":"5a864241ec2f2018","yearOfBirth":"1942","gender":"male","creationDate":"2009-01","numberOfNeutralVue":"0"}
{"Id":"8a75dacbe1c0d991","yearOfBirth":"1947","gender":"male","creationDate":"2004-01","numberOfNeutralVue":"0"}
```

(when I open at Blocknote txt) or if I use

```
Import["....json","CSV"]
```

While when I use `Import["...","JSON"]`, I get the error message, specifically

```
Import::jsonexpendofinput: Unexpected character found while looking for the end of input.
Import::jsonhintposandchar: An error occurred near character '"', at line 2:3
```

I will be grateful for any help how to proceed! (Moreover some of my files are rather big, more than 1 Gb, I know it is a separate question, but if you can also give advice on how to deal with chunks of such file, I will appreciate a lot!)

Comment: You could try something like ```stream = OpenRead@"~/test.ndjson";
ReadLine[stream] // Developer`ReadRawJSONString```.  You could replace the developer function with `Import[#, "JSON"]&` if you want to avoid undocumented functions.

Comment: Huh, thank you very much! At least something is finally happenning. Indeed I can see the lines from the file and the structure. But can you be so kind also to explain how I can collect those lines into chunks of lines (tables)? Sorry for my ignorance, but my experience so far is limited to working with mini csv and excel files....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Import[myfile.ndjson,"JSON"]` doesn't work because the file as a whole is not valid JSON.  But each *line* is valid JSON and so we can treat the file as a stream and read it one line at a time.  The simplest way to do this would be

```
stream = OpenRead@"~/test.ndjson";
ClearAll[line];
result = {};
While[line =!= EndOfFile,
    line = ReadLine[stream];
    If[StringQ[line] && !FailureQ[res = ImportString[line, "RawJSON"]],
        AppendTo[result, res]
    ]
 ];
```

The only real issue with this is the `AppendTo`, which can be a very inefficient way to grow a large list (so if you have many thousands of lines it could slow things down).

To get around this use the new [`"DynamicArray"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/DynamicArray.html) data structure:

```
stream = OpenRead@"~/test.ndjson";
ClearAll[line];
ds = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"];
While[line =!= EndOfFile,
    line = ReadLine[stream];
    If[StringQ[line] && !FailureQ[res = Developer`ReadRawJSONString[line]],
        ds["Append", res]
    ]
 ];
result = Normal[ds]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second does not work for me (maybe because ds is not defined and my attempts to define it fail). The first works but only with a small file. Is there any way to stop streaming the lines after say 10 000 lines and then restart a separate stream? Thanks a lot, really!

Comment: I added the definition for `ds`.  To stop the loop early you can adjust the line `line =!= EndOfFile` to something like `(line =!= EndOfFile) || (++i < 10000)` assuming you define `i=0` beforehand.

Comment: Thank you! I realised the issue is that "create data structure" is available only Mathematica 12, while mine is 11. Working out for chunks of line now, will let you know!

Comment: If you don't have the new `"DynamicArray"` data structure available you can fall back to the old ways to do this: Either use `Reap`/`Sow` or something like `result={result,res}` in the loop and a `result=Flatten[result]` in the end. These should both be performing reasonably well. You can find more details about the latter approach in other questions on this site, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/169).